# Reading configuration info from a file

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

first of all, I have a class 'item' in my code which has different fields such as 'id', 'name', 'isItem', int, string and boolean respectively. I would like to create a function that create an 'item' from an id given. I want this function to fetch the object in a database like Excel or something easy to edit manually.

It would be like :
[image: Example of Excel Sheet easily editable]

Ok then I tried your way by creating an ItemsContainer class like :

```
public class ItemsContainer : MonoBehaviour {
    public item[] items;
}
```

Then I tried to parse like :

```
var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText (Application.dataPath + "\\" + "json.txt");
ItemsContainer Items = JsonUtility.FromJson<ItemsContainer> (json);

Dictionary<int, item> its = new Dictionary<int, item> ();
its = Items.items.ToDictionary (x => x.id);
```

But it gives me `Cannot deserialize JSON to new instances of type 'ItemsContainer.'` I don't know why. The Json is an exact copy of your 'output' in a notepad...

The JSON looks like

```
{
  "items": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "Name": "Wood",
  "isItem": true
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "Name": "Stone",
  "isItem": true
}
]
}
```

And my item class is defined as :

```
public class item : MonoBehaviour {

public int id;
public string Name;
public bool isItem;

public item () {
    Name = "Nothing";
    isItem = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds good. Have you heard of Entity Framework?

Comment: No never, should i take a look at it ?

Comment: I don't know if Entity Framework will work in Unity3d. Have you considered saving it as a .json file (its just a text file) and using [the `JsonUtility` class](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html)?

Comment: Thats what I'm looking for but it seems like no... How can i get through it ?

Comment: Ohh good idea maybe i should try that you are right, I'll be back to tell u how it goes

Comment: Excel isn't a database.

Comment: You need to show what the class `item` looks like and what the content of `json.txt` is. Also double check that the variable `json` actually holds the text you expect it to. Have it print it to the console as a test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with configuration data like this the best approach is saving it as a .json file (its just a text file) and using [the `JsonUtility` class](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html).

If you set `JsonUtility.ToJson(yourClass, true)` the 2nd parameter turns on "prettyPrint" which makes it easier to edit in something like notepad. Just make a few "placeholder" items via code and call `.ToJson()` to get the initial file then you can edit it and add the rest.

```
[Serializable]
public class MyItem
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public bool isItem;
}

[Serializable]
public class ItemsContainer
{
    public MyItem[] items;
}

//elsewhere
public void SaveTemplate()
{
    List<MyItem> itemList = new List<MyItem>();
    itemList.Add(new MyItem { Id = 1, Name = "Wood", isItem = true });
    itemList.Add(new MyItem { Id = 2, Name = "Stone", isItem = true });

    ItemsContainer itemsContainer= new ItemsContainer ();
    itemsContainer.items = itemList.ToArray();

    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(itemsContainer, true);
    YourFunctionToSaveTheTextSomewhere(json);

}
```

This will create json text that looks similar to

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "Wood",
      "isItem": true
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "Name": "Stone",
      "isItem": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Which you can edit and add more items to then to get back you just do

```
public MyItem[] GetItems()
{
    string json = GetJsonTextSomehow();
    ItemsContainer container = JsonUtility.FromJson<ItemsContainer>(json);
    return container.items;
}
```

> I managed to have the json text but how can i call the id 45 for example and create an object from its specs ?

For that you will want to load the data in to a dictionary that is keyed by the id of the item, your code could look like this

```
public class ItemManager : MonoBehavior
{
    private Dictionary<int, MyItem> _itemDict;

    public void Awake()
    {
        var items = GetItems();

        //Makes a new dictionary from the array using the field Id as the key.
        _itemDict = items.ToDictionary(x => x.Id); 
    }

    public MyItem GetItem(int itemId)
    {
        return _itemDict[itemId];
    }

    private MyItem[] GetItems()
    {
        string json = GetJsonTextSomehow();
        ItemsContainer container = JsonUtility.FromJson<ItemsContainer>(json);
        return container.items;
    }

    private string GetJsonTextSomehow()
    {
       //...
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't get it to work im sad, "Cannot deserialize JSON to new instances of type 'ItemsContainer.' "

Comment: @Ay0m3 update your question with the code you used and the json you are trying to feed back in to it.

Comment: See the comment I made on the question, also delete your previous comments in my answer to clean it up

Comment: You don't have `[Serializable]` above the two classes in your edited question, is it there in the real code? if it is update your question. Also the class `item` should ***NOT*** derive from `MonoBehavior`, classes derived from `MonoBehavior` can't be serialized from json.